# Flow: shape types and additional optional fields

Tags: flowtype, structural-typing

I often find myself needing to do the following, and Flow makes it stupidly difficult:

```
/* @flow */

type Foo = {
  +foo?: number,
}

type FooBar = {
  +foo?: number,
  +bar?: number,
}

const foo: Foo = {foo: 2}

function process(arg: $ReadOnly<FooBar>) {
}

process(foo)
```

Is there any good way to do this?  I get the following error:

```
17: process(foo)
            ^ Cannot call `process` with `foo` bound to `arg` because property `bar` is missing in `Foo` [1] but exists in `FooBar` [2].
References:
12: const foo: Foo = {foo: 2}
               ^ [1]
14: function process(arg: $ReadOnly<FooBar>) {
                                    ^ [2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flow defaults to object types being inexact; this means that, although `Foo` is only declared to explicitly have a single (optional) property `foo` of type `number`, a variable of type `Foo` could theoretically have additional properties. For example, a variable of type `Foo` could have a property `bar`. And, since `bar` is not typed in `Foo`, `bar`'s type is unrestricted (i.e., not necessarily `number`). As a result, if you were to interact with `arg.bar` in `process` and Flow allowed `arg` to be of type `Foo`, you are not guaranteed to be interacting with a `number`. Thus, Flow complains.

One way to fix this is to use exact object types. If Flow knows that a variable of type `Foo` will never have a `bar` property, then it can safely be passed into `process`. So, you could type `Foo` as:

```
type Foo = {|
  +foo?: number,
|};
```

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgBiccYAvGAN4A+qYYA1FCQPwBcYAdgK4C2ARngBOAGlTUAvumz4iJAEIBDIeSp1GzOOy59Bo9Q37LtPAcLFTUAYzicAzhjCaOxUhUrOwAJktRunKwwAS1swHCE4Kzw7OwAKZQBzDgASACU8RQATAHlOGCwAHlclIQA+AEo1S3DI6LjNcqA)

(Note: the `$ReadOnly` utility type is not necessary with the above definition of `Foo` and the original definition of `FooBar` because `bar` is not writable. Though, certainly, it's fine to keep `$ReadOnly`.)

Comment: ah right, I always forget about this.  Do you have any idea if TypeScript is as strict about shape types?  I haven't had any situations yet where Flow's strictness about shape types is really worth the hassle.

Comment: [Flow will be making objects exact by default](https://medium.com/flow-type/on-the-roadmap-exact-objects-by-default-16b72933c5cf) so you won't have to worry about this soon. Not sure about TypeScript.